# How to solve Conda scrapy installation problem?

Tags: python-3.x, installation, scrapy, anaconda

I'm trying to run scrapy on Anaconda (windows 10).
I've installed it with conda command described on docs.
But it is not working.

in anaconda powershell virtual env. I installed with this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
```

It gives the below output:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\bld\scrapy_1564100571450\_h_env\python.exe"  "C:\Users\omar\Anaconda3\envs\deneme\Scripts\scrapy.exe" '
```

it seems like installation see wrong path for python, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in conda command:

conda uninstall scrapy

then

open anaconda navigator, open environment, search scrapy, and install